# UIScrollView paging add space between pages

Tags: uiscrollview, paging, space

I am using a UIScrollView with paging = true to display multiple UIViewControllers. That works fine. Now I am trying to add a space between the pages by following this answer [How to create a paging scrollView with space between views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361519)

However it does not work for me. When the UIScrollView stops scrolling the space (black) remains visible. I am using Swift 2 syntax and iOS 9.

[image: view1]
[image: view2] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, turns out I had an equal widths constraint stopping it paging at the right distance. See my post here: [Margin between images in UIScrollView - Swift version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617214/margin-between-images-in-uiscrollview-swift-version/42617718?noredirect=1#comment72401305_42617718)